# Mutable lists in python

Tags: python, list

```
def solution(a):
    res = a[:]
    while res and res[0] != res[-1]:
        c,*res,c = res
    return res
```

The code that I have provided above removes the first and last elements until they are the same however I am not able to understand how this works. I am getting confused by "c,*res,c = res" this line of code. It would be great if anyone could explain this.

Comment: See the (similar) unpacking answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338143/how-to-remove-the-first-and-last-item-in-a-list).

Comment: @wkl As far as I can see, that question doesn't ask for an explanation of this and none of the answers provide one (one merely uses it and drops a name).

Comment: @ishrajsingh I added an answer to the linked question and answer, going into a bit more detail about your specific example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338143/how-to-remove-the-first-and-last-item-in-a-list/73848365#73848365